# Issues here with CSS are:

Tags: html, css

I wish to know solutions to these kind of issues:

1. How can I make this grey rectangle dissapear on DESKTOP screen size?(do not know how did it end up right there)
2. How can I get these "Sign up..." text in the title section to be in one row(small fonts) instead of a two? ( I have tried inline-block etc, but it does not work)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@600;800&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: hsl(230, 100%, 99%);
  background: url('./images/bg-pattern.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 53%;
}

.main-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 32em;
}

.title-section {
  min-height: 25vh;
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
}

.title-section span {
  color: hsl(225, 20%, 60%);
}

.title-span-1 {
  padding-top: 0.65em;
}

.img-pattern {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 170px;
}

.card-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  min-height: 60vh;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


/* <----- CARD -----> */

.views-title {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  color: hsl(225, 20%, 60%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.slider-container .slider-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: hsl(230, 100%, 99%);
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.amount-container {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.amount {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.amount-text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: hsl(225, 20%, 60%);
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.billing-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: hsl(225, 20%, 60%);
}

.billing-month,
.billing-year {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

.billing-month {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.monthly-billing-text {
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.yearly-billing-text {
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}

.yearly-discount {
  color: hsl(15, 100%, 70%);
  background: hsl(14, 92%, 95%);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.billing-year {
  margin-left: 3em;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.billing-benefits {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.billing-benefits ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: hsl(225, 20%, 60%);
}

.billing-benefits li {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

li::before {
  content: '✓';
  color: hsl(174, 86%, 45%);
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.button-trial {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  width: 200px;
  background: hsl(227, 35%, 25%);
  color: hsl(226, 100%, 87%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* DESKTOP */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .main-section {
    width: 50em;
  }
  .card-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-areas: "main-title amount-container" "input input" "billing-area billing-area" "benefits-list benefits-list";
  }
  .title-section {
    grid-area: main-title;
  }
  .views-title {
    margin-top: 3em;
  }
  .slider-container {
    grid-area: input;
    margin: 2.5em;
  }
  .amount-container {
    grid-area: amount-container;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .billing-container {
    grid-area: billing-area;
  }
  .yearly-discount {
    position: relative;
  }
  .yearly-discount::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "discount";
    background: hsl(14, 92%, 95%);
    top: 20%;
    transform: translateY(-20%);
    width: 65px;
    left: 3.2em;
    line-height: 1.6;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  .billing-benefits {
    grid-area: benefits-list;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .billing-benefits ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .button-trial {
    grid-area: btn-trial;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive pricing component</title>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="title-section">
      <h1 class="main-title">Simple, traffic-based pricing</h1>
      <span class="title-span-1">Sign up for our 30-day trial.
            <br>
          <span class="title-span-2">No credit card required.</span>
      </span>
      <img src="./images/pattern-circles.svg" alt="background image pattern" class="img-pattern">
    </div>

    <div class="card-section">
      <h2 class="views-title">100K Pageviews</h2>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider-range">
      </div>
      <div class="amount-container">
        <span class="amount">$16.00<span class="amount-text">  /  month</span></span>
      </div>

      <div class="billing-container">
        <div class="billing-month">
          <span class="monthly-billing-text">Monthly Billing</span>
          <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
          <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
        </div>

        <div class="billing-year">
          <span class="yearly-billing-text">Yearly Billing</span>
          <span class="yearly-discount">-25%</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="billing-benefits">
        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited websites</li>
          <li>100% data ownership</li>
          <li>Email reports</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="button-trial">
              Start my trial
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and try to explain briefly what you want. Which grey rectangle you want to disappear in desktop view ?

Comment: Please see [ask], then 1) revise your post to  ask just one clear, specific question, and 2) revise your post _title_ to reflect that one clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap Text in one span

```
<span class="title-span-1">Sign up for our 30-day trial. No credit card required.</span>
```

Use [Media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) to get text In Mobile Responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .title-span-1{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```